# Conditionally delete DataTable Row in powershell?

Tags: .net, powershell, datatable

I am trying to remove a handful of rows from a .NET DataTable using Powershell, based on a list that I have. Here is my condensed code:

Here is my datatable declaration:

```
$Global:dt = New-Object System.Data.Datatable
$dt.Columns.Add("Name")
$dt.Columns.Add("AccountID")
```

I know I am populating my datatable correctly. Here is my code where I try and conditionally delete something:

```
$testname = "John Smith"

foreach ($id in $DeleteIDs)
{
     $dt.Select("Name = '" + $testname + "' AND AccountId = '" + $id + "'").Delete()
}
```

I may be crazy but I sware this worked for me the first time I tried it. But now I am receiving the following error:

```
Method invocation failed because [System.Data.DataRow[]] doesn't contain a method named 'Delete'.
At P:\My Documents\Scripts\myLoc\myScript.ps1:152 char:9
+         $dt.Select("Name= '" + $testname+ "' AND AccountId = '" + $id + "' ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound
```

This says System.Data.DataRow does not contain a `Delete` method. I know this isn't try. When I place a breakpoint and run a `$dt | gm` I get the following.

```
 PS C:\WINDOWS\system32>> $dt | gm


   TypeName: System.Data.DataRow
```

Comment: It says `System.Data.DataRow[]` doesn't contain a delete method, subtle but important difference - you're dealing with an array of `DataRow`s at this point. You need to iterate the collection to get access to the delete method of each object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to delete rows from a DataTable:

1. With `$dataTable.Rows.Remove($row)` (or `RemoveAt()`) method, which deletes the row **directly**
2. With `$row.Delete()`, which changes the state of the row to Deleted. After the loop, **you must call `dataTable.AcceptChanges()` to ensure these rows are effectively deleted**.

The documentation from Microsoft explaining exactly this can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/dataset-datatable-dataview/datarow-deletion).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @arco444 I was able to pinpoint the issue I was having. And I was not crazy.

My dataset that I am trying to remove from is constantly changing.

At the time it ran correctly, where I searched for `$testname` there was only 1 instance of that name in the entire dataset.

Today when I ran the script, there where multiple instances of `$testname` so it took it as an array of rows. The following fixed everything:

```
foreach ($id in $DeleteIDs)
{
     $rows = $dt.Select("Name = '" + $testname + "' AND AccountId = '" + $id + "'").Delete()

     foreach($row in $rows)
     {
          row.Delete()
     }
}
```

A variable will store an array of pointers to each row, so I can manually go through each one and delete it.

Comment: In your answer, I'm guessing you shouldn't have the .Delete() on the assignment and you should have a dollar sign on the row.Delete().